# Why is "x-men" tag not suitable for this question?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Why did Apocalypse destroy all nuclear weapons?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159970/why-did-apocalypse-destroy-all-nuclear-weapons)

Gallifreyan removed "x-men" tag from this question. Why is it wrong for this question to have "x-men" tag?

Answer (score 4):

### Probably based on the tag wiki

My best guess is that the editor was following the guidance in the tag wiki:

> Use this tag to refer to the mutant superhero team in the Marvel
>   Universe.

As such, questions about characters appearing in *X-Men* comics but not *belonging to the the X-Men team* would seem to be excluded. The question edited was such a question, asking only about Apocalypse (a mutant who does not belong to the X-Men).

**However, it may be that [x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men) is/should be used for any questions about X-Men franchises**. I’m not sure whether this question has ever been brought up, so perhaps current usage, whatever that may be, should be the guide.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Either the tag has to be changed to be about the comics and the franchise, or we have to clean it up from unrelated question (as per "tags have to reflect __what the question is about__, not what it mentions"). I was doing the latter, because that's what the excerpt currently says.

Answer (score 3):

Most other teams like this, or even individuals, were explicitly made franchise tags during the recent cleanup. This was simply missed then, otherwise I would have added it to more questions and updated the wiki.

Since that's all said and done, changing it now probably needs a consensus.

But to match current usage it should be updated as in:

- [ant-man](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ant-man)
- [guardians-of-the-galaxy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy)
- [thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thor)
- [avengers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers) (Note, wiki guidance not updated but actual usage should have been)